# jQuery + Greasmonkey: mouseover() is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, greasemonkey

In an effort to make my script more <strike>undetectable</strike> robust, I've decided to use more human events, ie mouseover, mousedown, mouseup, mouseout. As these are jQuery dependant, I have added

```
// @require      https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js
```

to the top of my script, and, as per the instructions at the [Greasmonkey Wiki](https://wiki.greasespot.net/Third-Party_Libraries#Potential_conflict) included this line:

```
this.$ = this.jQuery = jQuery.noConflict(true);
```

When I run this script, I get this error in the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementsByClassName(...)[0].mouseover is not a function
```

This would lead me to believe that jQuery hasn't been loaded on the script install. I have tried the same code without the 'noConflict' and it effectivey breaks the site, as well as still returning the aforementioned error.

Here is my Code:

```
else if (document.getElementsByClassName('thumb-container active')[0] == null &&
         document.getElementsByClassName('feed-ajax-next')[0] != null){
         document.getElementsByClassName('feed-ajax-next')[0].mouseover();
         console.log("M_over");
         document.getElementsByClassName('feed-ajax-next')[0].mousedown();
         console.log("M_down");
         document.getElementsByClassName('feed-ajax-next')[0].mouseup();
         console.log("M_up");
         document.getElementsByClassName('feed-ajax-next')[0].mouseout();
         console.log("M_out");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`document.getElementsByClassName()` doesn't return a jQuery object, but `mouseover()` and the other functions are jQuery functions.

In that case, you need to use `jQuery('.feed-ajax-next')` to get the element as a jQuery object and then use the function like this -  `jQuery('.feed-ajax-next').mouseover()`

You can read more about jQuery objects here: https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/jquery-object/

Comment: Nice quick answer! Thanks!